# Chart not moving fluently when adding value to two lines on interval

Tags: highcharts

I'm using an updating spline chart to show a line that changes each second. The changing is set in chartinfo.chart.events.load. Below is the code I'm using in my actual program:

```
chartinfo.chart.events.load: function() {
    powerLine = this.series[0];
    setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = ((latestPowerValue > maxPower) ? maxPower : ((latestPowerValue < minPower) ? minPower : latestPowerValue)); //Math.random() * 250;
        powerLine.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 1000);
}
```

I have another updating spline chart to show two lines which also changes each second. This is almost the same as the above example but this time two series are updated.

```
chartinfo.chart.events.load: function() {
    var minLine = this.series[0];
    var maxLine = this.series[1];

    setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime();
        var ymin = ((latestVoltageMin > maxVoltage) ? maxVoltage : ((latestVoltageMin < minVoltage) ? minVoltage : latestVoltageMin));
        var ymax = ((latestVoltageMax > maxVoltage) ? maxVoltage : ((latestVoltageMax < minVoltage) ? minVoltage : latestVoltageMax));

        minLine.addPoint([x, ymin], true, true);
        maxLine.addPoint([x, ymax], true, true);
    }, 1000);
};
```

I have also prepared working examples of [the single lined (working) graph](http://jsfiddle.net/N89tC/) and [the double lined (not working) graph](http://jsfiddle.net/cRgUr/) in jsFiddle.

I'd like to find out how to get the double lined graph to move/slide like the single lined graph. Any help or insight into the problem is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the first add point's animate parameter to false, the second add point will animate for the both of them.

```
series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRgUr/1/)

Comment: Oddly enough this does work for the jsFiddle example, but not for my real web page. For some reason `minLine` follows the `maxLine` as if the values are the same. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you could reproduce issue on jsFiddle, it would be nice - maybe some of your variables are the same?

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce and set everything the exact same way as my real code inside jsFiddle but it keeps working correctly. The only difference is that I use `Math.random()` In the jsFiddle code. I also output `ymin` and `ymax` right before they are inserted into the addPoint function. They contain the correct values. From this test I only found out that they are both following the ymax value, ignoring the ymin value.

Comment: I thought I was losing my mind but I finally reproduced it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ubrda/ Any idea why this is hapening?

Comment: I guess this is a whole new issue, I will create a new question. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 
series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);

also write chart.redraw(); after series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true); 
This makes it work for me in webapp