# Multiple Charts not moving in sync at random times when adding value on interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts, timeserieschart

I am trying to create dynamic number of series from UI. Upon selection, backend updates one entry at the time. While the graphs are running fine at most times. At some random time the two series move out of sync as in http://jsfiddle.net/cRgUr/ 
    and come back in sync after few seconds. I have referred following links for resolution but still see the issue.
    [Chart not moving fluently when adding value to two lines on interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917887/chart-not-moving-fluently-when-adding-value-to-two-lines-on-interval?rq=1) and [Updating spline chart two lines on top of eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920774/updating-spline-chart-two-lines-on-top-of-eachother/47752291#47752291)
    Below is the code snippet :

```
function getInitialData(series){
                 var arrayOfValues=[];
                $http({
                        mode:'cors',
                        method:'GET',
                        url: '/getData',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json' },
                        cache: false,
                        }).success(function(data) { 

                  arrayOfValues.push(/*populated by backend*/); // E.g values for y for number of series selected. If 2 series are to be drawn, at a time this array will contain arrayOfValue[0]= y value for series 1, arrayOfValue[1]=y value for series 2

                  }
                 drawgraph(series,arrayOfValues,newWidgetMetrics/*widget selected from UI*/);
                   } ).error(function(data) {
                               });
                function drawgraph(series,arrayOfValues,newWidgetMetrics1){
                         var time = (new Date()).getTime();
                    for(let p=0;p<arrayOfValues.length;p++){
                        if(p<arrayOfValues.length-1){
                                series[p].addPoint([time,arrayOfValues[p]] ,false
                                  , (series[0].data.length >= 20));// set false for all series but the last, with an animation where we want the line to start plotting after 20 seconds                    
                    }
                         else{
                            series[p].addPoint([time,arrayOfValues[p]] , true
                                      , (series[0].data.length >= 20));// set true for only the last series, with an animation where we want the line to start plotting after 20 seconds                            
                     }
                        chart.redraw();
                    }
                    arrayOfValues=[];
            }

            dataSeries=function(){
                for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
                    var obj={};
                    obj.type="line";
                    obj.data=getData();
                    obj.boostThreshold=60;
                    obj.name=newWidgetLegends[i];
                    tArray.push(obj);

                }

                return tArray;
            }

              func_plot();



            function func_plot(){ 

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    Highcharts.setOptions({
                        global: {
                            useUTC: false
                        }
                    });

                 chart=Highcharts.chart(divId, {
                    chart: {
                        height:'38%',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        type: 'spline',
                        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                            marginRight: 10,

                        events: {
                             load: function () {
                                 maxSamples = 60,
                                 counter = 0;
                                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                                var ser = this.series;

//                              setTimeout(function () {
                                setInterval(function (){
                                            window['arr' + count]=[];
                                        getInitialData(ser);


                            }, 1000);
                                }, 2000);


                            }
                        }
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        style: {
                            display: 'none'
                        }
                    },

                   exporting: {
                          buttons: {
                            contextButton: {
                              y:screen.height*-0.02
                            }
                          }
                        },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                       events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                             return false; 
                                }
                            }

                       },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        ordinal:false,
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value:%M:%S}'
                          },
                        tickInterval: 10000,
                        title: {
                            text: newWidetXLabel,
                            marginBottom: 100
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text:newWidetYLabel,
                            min: 0,
                            max:10
                        },

                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },


                   legend: {
                      title: {
                          text: '',
                          style: {
                              fontStyle: 'italic'
                          }
                      },
                      layout: 'horizontal',
                      align: 'right',
                      verticalAlign: 'top',
                      x: -30,
                      y: -17
                  },


                boost: {
                    seriesThreshold:2,
                    useGPUTranslations: true
                },

                    credits: {
                      enabled: false
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                    },

                    series: dataSeries()
                });
                });
        }

            $(window).resize(function() {
                height = chart.height,
                width = chart.width,
                chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = false);
            });

    }
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors, I tried formatting it but had to give up. I'm surprised it runs at all.

Comment: Sorry for that, this is just a code chunk that I have extracted from a larger program and hence dependencies. Hence may not really run for you. Still I hope to get some help regarding the issue that I am facing that the two series go out of sync at random time and come back in sync after few seconds.  In other posts the issue has a continues occurance and is resolved by setting animation false for all the series but the last. series[p].addPoint([time,arrayOfValues[p]] , false
                                      , (series[0].data.length >= 20));  How do I debug my scenario ?

Comment: Well, it is one function, and as such, it shouldnt have syntax errors. There are closing braces missing. I'm not talking about missing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because both series are not being drawn at the same moment. Second argument of the `addPoint` function is a flag that indicates whether the chart should be redrawn immediately after the addition or not. In your code 2 redraws happen instead of one. The update of the second series breaks the animation of the first one (it has no time to finish).

The **solution** here is to redraw the chart only after the second call of `addPoint()`:

```
 series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
 series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/5y1dacxv/

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint